# How to remove custom script extensions on multiple Azure VMs parallelly?

Tags: azure, devops

I am working on Devops project to run QA powershell codes as custom script extensions . I need to run it on multiple Virtual machines (minimum 10). I figured out how to install custom script extension parallelly in VMs. But I did not find a solution uninstall custom script extensions parallelly in Vms . Please help. I am ok with ARM template or using Azure CLI .

Comment: why do you need to uninstall? just tear down the VMs when you're done with them

Comment: I am doing the pester script validation using custom script extension. I need to uninstall the CustomScript extension to run the custom script again when I trigger the run. VM supports only one custom script to added to it. I need to  uninstall the custom script before running it again.

Comment: Would it work for you that you trigger 1 script and that "master" script trigger the next script and so on?

Comment: Hi @Jarnstrom, I am using ansible playbook with Azure CLI to run the uninstall custom script extension. So not sure if I can use a driver script. Please let me know your comments.

Answer (score 0):

one way would be to use jobs, something like this (rough sketch):

```
"vm1","vm2","vm3" | Foreach-Object {
    Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
        Remove-AzureRMVMCustomScriptExtension -ResourceGroupName xxx -VmName $using:PSItem -Name extensionname -Force
    }
}
```

the above will work if you have azurermcontextautosave enabled. ARM Templates are not capable of removing custom script extension, you might experiment with `Complete` mode, but its a bit dangerous.

But honestly you just need to use `forceUpdateTag` to just force extension to rerun, without removing it

Comment: Thankyou for your comments. But we are using Ansible to execute the azure custom script uninstall step. If you can convert this to Azure CLI, that wil be great. Force update tag wont be suitable for my requirement because the extension name might be different for each of the VMs so I cannot use forceupdatetag without giving the extension name? Please let me know your comments.

Comment: just force the extension name, or make it calculatable, or just query it before. ansible is capable of running powershell, so thats not an issue really.